# Create multiple sheets in excel using pandas to loop through sheet names

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create multiple sheets in excel, using pandas integration with xlsxwriter in Python, based on data represented in categories

```
Categories ="Autoimmune Diseases","Blood","Cancer: Head & Neck","Cancer: Hematological","Cancer: Other","Cardiovascular","Dermatological Treatment","Eyes","Immune Deficiencies","Infectious Diseases","Liver Disease","Neurological","Neurotology","Pain Management","Rare Diseases","Respiratory Diseases","Women's Health"
```

Right now my code looks like:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(Individualreport, engine='xlsxwriter')
Categories ="Autoimmune Diseases","Blood","Cancer: Head & Neck","Cancer: Hematological","Cancer: Other","Cardiovascular","Dermatological Treatment","Eyes","Immune Deficiencies","Infectious Diseases","Liver Disease","Neurological","Neurotology","Pain Management","Rare Diseases","Respiratory Diseases","Women's Health"

Overview = pd.read_excel(READ,sheet_name='Overview', header=None)
OverviewCols = pd.read_excel(READ, sheet_name='Overview', header=None,nrows=1).values[0]
Overview.columns = OverviewCols

auto = Overview.loc[(Overview['Category']=="Autoimmune Diseases")]
auto.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Auto', startrow= over_row, startcol=over_col, header=False, index=False)
```

and I would have to repeat for all 17 categories to make each sheet like:

```
blood = Overview.loc[(Overview['Category']=="Blood")]
blood.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Blood', startrow= over_row, startcol=over_col, header=False, index=False)
```

**Is there a way to loop through the list to simplify the code? I know this isn't right, but something like:**

```
for i in Categories:
    i = Overview.loc[(Overview['Category']==i)]
    i.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i, startrow= over_row, startcol=over_col, header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

referring to your code:

```
for i in Categories:
    i = Overview.loc[(Overview['Category']==i)]
    i.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i, startrow= over_row, startcol=over_col, header=False, index=False)
```

The variable "Categories" is a tuple of strings - you are trying to use a string "i" as a variable e.g.:

```
"Blood" = Overview.loc[(Overview['Category']=="Blood")
```

which won t work.

Have your tried to use a free variable name?

```
for cat in Categories:
    test = Overview.loc[(Overview['Category']==cat)]
    test.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=cat, startrow=over_row, startcol=over_col, header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: I did try that, thanks for having me try it again! Silly mistake, I guess I didn't read my error very closely earlier.  It wasn't working because I had : in some of the category names and xlsxwriter doesn't like that character.

Comment: as an alternative to xlsxwriter you could try openpyxl - dunno why but i prefer it